# Why is water such a poor electromagnetic conductor?

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light, waves, water

1.-Why does salt water not conduct any form of non-visible light?

2.-Why does it conduct red light so much worse than other colours? (Why does it absorb red so much and not blue, for example).

It's my first question by the way. :)

Comment: Is salt water really that different from regular water?

Comment: An your question concerning underwater acoustics: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underwater_acoustics#Surface

Comment: I would recommend you to split the question in two: the EM part and the acoustic part. It is too broad to be answered in one.

Comment: See [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_absorption_by_water#Visible_region)

Comment: @Timeless Yes of course it is. It has ions dissolved in it. In fact, salt water **IS** conductive and regular water isn't. So just by their basic properties, it is. And about the wikipedia aarticle, I've read it, but it does not answer my question. Victor I'll edit the sound part out and ask it again, thanks.

Comment: @Pablowako: Yes, salt water is more conductive but the impact on the refractive index is rather low: n=1.342 for regular and n=1.349 for salt water (3.9 %) at 400nm. At 700nm, it is 1.329 vs. 1.335. Source: Handbook of optics, table 3, p 1.19, ISBN: 978-0-07-149892

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking about the absorption of Light by Matter:

It depends on the atomic make-up of the matter at hand, Hydrogen or Salt or Spaghetti, what kinds of wavelengths can be absorbed. It takes different amounts of energy to raise the electrons of different atoms and molecules - such as H2O or Na or Cl - to higher energy levels. Now, every wave-length of light (red, blue, green) has a different energy.

In the case of complex matter, such as a mixture of Salt and Water (and probably remnants of detergent and stuff) there are many different kinds of electron orbits (remember the s p d f stuff?) and some bonds (ion bonds, hydrogen bonds) which respond to different levels of energy.

In the case of liquid water, it seems that red light hits the spot pretty nicely, as far as what energy is needed to raise the water's electrons to higher energy levels. Blue doesn't.

If the energy of the light is used to raise the electrons, the light doesn't come out anymore - it has been absorbed!

But blue light has more energy than red light! Why doesn't it just raise the "weaker" electrons up, too?

Because the energy levels are quantized. Meaning, if you don't hit it right on, you don't get anywhere. Look here for further reading: [Interactions of Radiation with Matter](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod3.html#c1)

> The energy levels for all physical processes at the atomic and molecular levels are quantized, and if there are no available quantized energy levels with spacings which match the quantum energy of the incident radiation, then the material will be transparent to that radiation, and it will pass through.

Comment: So how come only ELF and visible light travel through (salt) water? Normally higher electromagnetic frequencies tend to easily pass through everything (except concrete and lead).

Answer (score 0):

For the acoustic part, yes it is difficult for sound or for that matter any wave would find it difficult to travel from one medium to another, the reason we are able to observe this is that speed of sound is not very large, and a change is detected. In case of light, the speed of light in water is 2.24 x 10^8 m/s the change is more than 25%. And that of sound in water about 1500 m/s at 25° C, as compared to air at 340 m/s.   Imagine, you are riding a car (which can travel in both air and water) going at the speed of sound, you suddenly see that there is a water body, and you go right in. How do you feel? You feel and acceleration of 1150m/(s^2), if your car took 1 second to change mediums. And you experience a force of 57500 newtons, that is more than than the weight of a large excavator. The result: Simple, you'd be crushed.  Now imagine the same situation, if you were travelling at speed of light. My calculations show that you'd be experiencing 7.6 x 10^7 m/(s^2) and that change is incomparable.  My objective is to inform you that wave experience immense "pressure" as they traverse mediums. They lose lots of energy while changing mediums.

Comment: So if they were travelling from water to air they'd experience a huge **deceleration** right? So water sounds would sound much louder then, wouldn't they?